# Duvidas em como fazer herança com PHP utilizando Framework CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou com duvidas para utilizar herança com PHP utilizando o *frame* CodeIgniter.

1. Preciso criar uma classe *abstract*?
2. Como faço para buscar um campo que está em determinada classe?

Ex: A Classe de Produtos tem os campos:
 - nome
 - preco_venda

Já na classe Categorias preciso inserir qual categoria este produto compõe.
  Atributo:
    - nome

Alguém teria algum material que trata sobre este assunto?

Comment: Tu já deve ter lido a documentação, mas né... https://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: Sim já consultei.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que tu confundiu o conceito de herança (que pode ser visto [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heran%C3%A7a_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))), com relacionamento de objetos.
Pelo que entendi, tu tens uma classe Produto, na qual queres ter as informações de Nome, Preço de Venda e Categoria e tens também uma outra classe Categoria que tu tens a informação de Nome.

Pois bem, pra saber a qual categoria o produto em questão pertence, tu tens primeiramente normalizar as classes ficando assim:

> **Classe Produto** com os atributos id_produto, id_categoria, nome, 
>   preco_venda.
>
> **Classe Categoria** com os atributos id_categoria, nome.

Dessa forma é que tu faz o relacionamento correto dos objetos.
Para funcionar a tua consulta dos dados, deverá ler os conceitos de chave primária e chave estrangeira [aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-aprenda-a-utilizar-a-chave-primaria-e-a-chave-estrangeira/37636) .